# How to get a local shape name from a BeforeShapeDelete event in Visio

Tags: vba, visio

I've created an event sink module using this code I found online (can't remember where it was now, it was from a tutorial). It's split into a class module and a standard module.

The standard module:

```
Option Explicit
 
Private mEventSink As clsEventSink
 
Dim vsoDocumentEvents As Visio.EventList        'Events of the Document class

'DOCUMENT-CLASS EVENTS
Dim vsoDocumentSavedEvent As Visio.Event
Dim vsoPageAddedEvent As Visio.Event
Dim vsoShapesDeletedEvent As Visio.Event
    
Private Const visEvtAdd% = &H8000

Public Sub CreateEventObjects()
 
    'Create an instance of the clsEventSink class
    'to pass to the AddAdvise method.
    Set mEventSink = New clsEventSink
    
    'Get the EventList collection of the active document.
    Set vsoDocumentEvents = ActiveDocument.EventList
    Set vsoAppEvents = Application.EventList

    'Add an Event object for the BeforeShapeDelete event.
    Set vsoShapesDeletedEvent = vsoDocumentEvents.AddAdvise(visEvtCodeShapeDelete, mEventSink, "", "Shapes deleted...")
    
    'Add an Event object for the DocumentSaved event.
    Set vsoDocumentSavedEvent = vsoDocumentEvents.AddAdvise(visEvtCodeDocSave, mEventSink, "", "Document saved...")
     
    'Add an Event object for the PageAdded event.
    Set vsoPageAddedEvent = vsoDocumentEvents.AddAdvise(visEvtAdd + visEvtPage, mEventSink, "", "Page added...")
 
End Sub
 
Public Sub DeleteEventObjects()

    'Delete the Event object for the DocumentSaved event.
    vsoDocumentSavedEvent.Delete
    Set vsoDocumentSavedEvent = Nothing

    
    'Delete the Event object for the PageAdded event.
    vsoPageAddedEvent.Delete
    Set vsoPageAddedEvent = Nothing
 
    'Delete the Event object for the ShapesDeleted event.
    vsoShapesDeletedEvent.Delete
    Set vsoShapesDeletedEvent = Nothing

End Sub
```

And the class module:

```
Implements Visio.IVisEventProc

Private Const visEvtAdd% = &H8000
 
Private Function IVisEventProc_VisEventProc( _
    ByVal nEventCode As Integer, _
    ByVal pSourceObj As Object, _
    ByVal nEventID As Long, _
    ByVal nEventSeqNum As Long, _
    ByVal pSubjectObj As Object, _
    ByVal vMoreInfo As Variant) As Variant
    

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Select Case nEventCode
         Case visEvtCodeDocSave
            'YOUR CODE FOR WHAT HAPPENS WHEN THE USER SAVES THE DOCUMENT GOES HERE
             Debug.Print "DocumentSaved (" & Hex(nEventCode) & ")"
    
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
         Case (visEvtPage + visEvtAdd)
            Debug.Print "Page Added (" & Hex(nEventCode) & ")"
    
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
         Case visEvtCodeShapeDelete
            'YOUR CODE FOR WHAT HAPPENS WHEN THE USER DELETES A SHAPE GOES HERE
            'Debug.Print "ShapesDeleted(" & Hex(nEventCode) & ")"
            
            Debug.Print pSubjectObj.PrimaryItem.Name
            'returns Sheet.??? instead of the desired local name
            
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
         Case Else
            'YOUR CODE FOR WHAT HAPPENS WHEN AN EVENT NOT LISTED ABOVE OCCURS, GOES HERE
             Debug.Print "Other (" & Hex(nEventCode) & ")"
    End Select
     
End Function
```

Now, my question in particular is about the `BeforeShapeDelete` event. When I delete a shape, I've set up the code to print to Visual Basic's debug window the name of the shape that will be deleted. The only issue is, it prints the global name (e.g. `Sheet.1`, `Sheet.2`, `Sheet.3`, etc.) If I were to create a shape, rename it using the `Shape Name` menu in the Developer tab to something else, e.g. "Square", and then delete that shape, it still prints a shape name of the form `Shape.XX` rather than whatever I renamed it to. How can I get the non-global shape name instead? I've tried `pSubjectObj.PrimaryItem.LocalName` but that doesn't come up as a valid property of the class object.

Comment: You're listening to the "DeletedEvent" rather than the "BeforeDeletedEvent" so the result is the shape is already in a deleted state (even though .Stat reports normal).  Both .Name and .NameU only return the Sheet.n names as you've discovered.  I agree with Nikolay that the WithEvents will be a simpler way to go.  Also I looked at this in a course I did and you can see the files here: https://visualsignals.typepad.co.uk/vislog/2017/01/course-files-for-visio-flyby-for-developers-on-ch9.html  (see Events/VBA WithEvents folder + you might be interested in the C# VSTO Events Demo using AddAdvise)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the answer to your question (why you don't get name there), but maybe I could suggest something. Please note that when you try to access the shape identifier, the shape is already deleted. If you want to be notified before deletion, you could use `visEvtCodeBefSelDel` code.

Or better yet, don't use AddAdvise/VisEventProc (unless you absolutely have to for whatever reason), and go with a simple straightforward approach of using "BeforeSelectionDelete" event. Meaning, remove the class module, and instead of your code, simply put in "ThisDocument":

```vb
Private Sub Document_BeforeSelectionDelete(selection)
  Debug.Print selection.PrimaryItem.Name
End Sub
```

And it should work.

Comment: If the user selects several shapes and presses the delete key I want this code to run for each of them, not just one time. So I don't think ```BeforeSelectionDelete``` will work for me

Comment: Then you are out of luck I guess.. There is no "before shape delete", only "before selection delete" (even with the AddAdvise/VisEventProc). You can iterate over the selection being deleted to find out which shapes are being deleted though.

Comment: Ok, how can I iterate through each shape in the selection?

Comment: Using for-each statement? For Each shape in Selection